# VSTO Outlook: Understanding what is Inline response and what's the difference between ActiveInlineResponse and ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I am very new to VSTO Outlook Add-in and sometimes I get lost with terminology.
I have some code for an Outlook Add-in which was made by a colleague and now I am maintaining it.

In code I see things like checking whether it is an inline response so my first question is: what is inline response exactly?

Also I see a line of code which converts an ActiveInlineResponse into an Outlook.MailItem and check if this conversion is null or not. If not null then it is an inline response and there is a warning comment saying not to try calling ActiveInlineResponse in case of Outlook 2010 because then Add-in crashes because in Outlook 2010 there is no inline response. I have seen that there is also a function called ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor. So my second question is: what is the difference between calling ActiveInlineResponse and ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor? What is the difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is inline response exactly?

Starting from Outlook 2013 in the Explorer window you may reply or forward items instantly. See it live on the video I've found on youtube - [Microsoft Office Outlook 2013: Using Inline Replies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6zzciMX91I). That feature is called inline response.

> what is the difference between calling ActiveInlineResponse and ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor? What is the difference between these two functions?

The [ActiveInlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) property returns an item object representing the active inline response item in the explorer reading pane, for example, it can be a `MailItem`.

The [ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponsewordeditor) property returns the Word Document object of the active inline response that is displayed in the explorer Reading Pane. This property returns `Null` (`Nothing` in Visual Basic) if no inline response is visible in the `Reading Pane`. The returned Word Document object provides access to most of the Word object model. So, that is not an Outlook item or object.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Eugene's comment, the crash in Outlook 2010 would be due to the call going past the COM object's v-table - these properties were added in Outlook 2013.

If you need to support Outlook 2010 (or earlier), you should be using the Outlook 2010 interop. If you need to access Outlook 2013+ features, do so using late binding (reflection) to avoid crashes.